# Dividing two results of count with eachother in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have two results of COUNT() that I would like to divide, but it doesn't work when I try to combine it into a single query. I get 'syntax error at or near "SELECT"' when I try to run this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(student.userid) FROM borrowed CROSS JOIN student WHERE student.userid = borrowed.userid AND current_date > expiredate AND returndate IS NULL / SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM student;
```

The code is supposed to get a percentage of 'Students' who are currently late returning a book to a library. The two code snippets separated by the '/' both work fine individually. The left one:

```
SELECT COUNT(student.userid) FROM borrowed CROSS JOIN student WHERE student.userid = borrowed.userid AND current_date > expiredate AND returndate IS NULL;
```

generates a count table containing the value 2. The right one:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM student;
```

generates a count table containing the value 15.

What I want to get is the percentage. So 2/15 should get me something like 13,3 %. How do I solve this as a singe query? The division has to be made float (or other decimal) somehow. Could someone provide me with a query that solves this problem? Thank you <3

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM... ) FROM ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(student.userid)::decimal / (SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM student) 
FROM borrowed 
CROSS JOIN student 
WHERE student.userid = borrowed.userid 
     AND current_date > expiredate AND returndate IS NULL;
```

Comment: @KTHKarl . . . This does not do what you want.  It counts the number of *late books* not students.  In addition, it is much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.student_id) / s.num_students
FROM borrowed b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_students FROM student) s
WHERE b.current_date > expiredate AND b.returndate IS NULL;
```

In particular, this counts the number of *students* not *late books*.  So a student with two late books is only counted once, not twice.